# How can I prove corollary 7.4 in Eisenbud's commutative algebra book?

Tags: commutative-algebra, implicit-function-theorem, hensels-lemma

Eisenbud states the following corollary to Hensel's lemma:

Given a polynomial $f(t,x)$ over a field $k$, with $x=a$ a simple root of $f(0,x)$, then there exists a unique power series $x(t) \in k[[t]]$ with $x(0) = a$  and $f(t,x(t)) = 0$ identically. His hint is to use the complete local ring $R = k[[t]]$ for $R[x]$.

Since $a$ is a simple root of $f(0,a)$, we know that $f'(t,a) \neq 0$. But, I'm not sure why
$$
\begin{split}
f(t,a) &\equiv 0 \pmod{f'(a)\cdot (t)} \\ &= 0 \pmod{\alpha\cdot(t)}
\end{split}
$$
This would hold of course if $f(t,a) \equiv f(0,a)$, but I'm not sure this is the case.

Comment: But $f'(a)$ is a nonzero element of the field, and therefore $f'(a)\cdot(t)=(t)$. I think it will all be clear if you write $f(t,x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty g_i(x)t^i$